# Passing array's element values to lowest or highest functions in pine script

Tags: arrays, integer, pine-script

I am trying to pass dynamic values to lowest and highest built-in functions in pine script from arrays. Below is the code

```
int[] pArray = array.new_int(0)
```

pArray is populated with int elements. Here is the code below that works.

```
fromInd         =   array.min(pArray)
lowest          =   ta.lowest(MACDHist,array.get(pArray,0))
Debug = label.new(bar_index+1, close, 'pArray: ' + str.tostring(pArray) + str.tostring(fromInd))
```

The [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvu3T.png) of above code on the chart is

```
pArray: [2, 15, 40]2
```

2 is the 0th index value of pArray that is printed outside of the array in the end. However when I change the label to output 'lowest' value (shown below) [nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH9mI.png) prints to chart but everything compiles well with **no errors or warnings**.

```
Debug = label.new(bar_index+1, close, 'pArray: ' + str.tostring(pArray) + str.tostring(lowest))
```

The output of 'array.get(id, index)' is series int because pArray is initialized to int. I also typecasted the 'array.get(id, index)' argument by enclosing it with 'int()' but nothing is working for the last line code except when hard coded.

'ta.lowest(source, length)' accepts series int arguments for length and it can also accept dynamic lengths as shown by tradingview https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-functions-support-dynamic-length-arguments-20554/

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

I tried a variation of a solution posted by first user below with code

```
//@version=5
indicator("Dynamic INT array length", overlay = false, max_bars_back = 5000)

[a, b, hist] = ta.macd(close, 26, 12, 9)

int[] lengths = array.new_int()
int[] nlengths = array.new_int()

for i = 0 to 10
    if hist[i] > 0
        array.unshift(lengths, i)
    else    
        array.unshift(nlengths,i)

lowest = ta.lowest(hist, array.get(lengths,0))

plot(lowest)
plot(hist, color = color.red)

debug = label.new(x = bar_index, y = 0, style = label.style_label_left, text = str.tostring(lowest) + "   " + str.tostring(lengths) + "   " + str.tostring(array.get(lengths,0)))
label.delete(debug[1])
```

and Im getting an error when using 'ta.lowest(hist, array.min(lengths))' where it says

```
Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0.0) in the "lowest" function. It must be > 0.
```

I tried all variations of the condition hist[i] > 0 within the for loop but nothing is printing and it has the same error. Let me know if there is an easy fix for this. Thanks.

Comment: Dynamic lengths do work, even when obtained from a valid array. However you have not provided enough information for anyone to be able to help you. Consider providing at the very least the error codes generated along with the code lines and ideally compilable minimum reproducible code.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for tips. I added more info with images.

Answer (score 1):

It should be working, at a guess, normally I'd say there must be something going on with how the array is populated, but it doesn't seem to be the case here given the array output. It's unlikely, but possible you've found a bug, or an even possibly an exception that isn't being picked up by the compiler.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Dynamic INT array length", overlay = false, max_bars_back = 5000)


int[] lengths = array.new_int()

for i = 0 to 10
    array.unshift(lengths, int(math.random(30, 50)))


[a, b, hist] = ta.macd(close, 26, 12, 9)

lowest = ta.lowest(hist, array.min(lengths))

plot(lowest)
plot(hist, color = color.red)

debug = label.new(x = bar_index, y = 0, style = label.style_label_left, text = str.tostring(lowest) + "   " + str.tostring(lengths) + "   " + str.tostring(array.min(lengths)))
label.delete(debug[1])
```

Follow up answer :

There's actually two things you need to take care of. If you consider when `hist` has been < 0 for a while (ie at least 10 bars). The first time `hist` crosses the zero line, your lengths array will only have one value : zero, and it can't be used in `ta.lowest()`. The second issue you will have is, if `hist` has been under zero the entire 10 bar window, the lengths array will be empty and `array.get(lengths, 0)` will give you the out of bounds indexing error.

You'll have to decide how to handle these specific circumstances, but the following of how you could account for it. For example using a length of 5 when the array has only one value of 0 and populating the arrays with `na` values to avoid the empty array problem.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Dynamic INT array length", overlay = false, max_bars_back = 5000)

[a, b, hist] = ta.macd(close, 26, 12, 9)

int[] lengths = array.new_int()
int[] nlengths = array.new_int()

for i = 0 to 10
    if hist[i] > 0
        array.unshift(lengths, i)
        array.unshift(nlengths, na)
    else    
        array.unshift(nlengths,i)
        array.unshift(lengths, na)


int len = na
if array.get(lengths, 0) > 0
    len := array.get(lengths, 0)
else
    len := 5

lowest = ta.lowest(hist, len)

plot(lowest)
plot(hist, color = color.red)

debug = label.new(x = bar_index, y = 0, style = label.style_label_left, text = str.tostring(lowest) + "   " + str.tostring(lengths) + "   " + str.tostring(array.get(lengths,0)))
label.delete(debug[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @rumpypumpydumpy! I was racking my head around it for awhile. Yours works so I'll try different versions of it.

Comment: @numpypumpydumpy posted a variation of your solution in my question above but it gave me an error, which I think might give a clue about whats going on. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for latest rendition of this issue. The for loop iterable i was always from 0 to 99 or larger. I changed it to 10 for debugging. But even with a length of hundred, a MACD above 0 (or below) at say index 35, 35 doesn't get detected and loaded onto the array. Thats been the real headscratcher for me.

Comment: Doesn't get detected or throws an error? Because even with a longer length, if you consider when the script is executing on historical bars, for example on say it's execution on bar 3, and bar 1 & 2 were both below zero, bar three would be the first bar that's above zero and so it would still result in a length of zero being generated and halting the script with the ta.lowest can't accept 0.0 length error.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the na elements of the array with 0? nz(lengths,0) is not working as datatypes do not match. I suppose we can use array.set() but I do not know which indexes have the 'na' elements dynamically.

Comment: Yes, you could do that, by using array.unshift(nlengths, 0) instead of na in the for loop.